# How to loop JOIN

Tags: php, mysql

I have this table data in the picture. It basically consists of name of places and **to which other place it belongs** in the same table. The field `belongs_to` refers to the `id` of the other place.

[image]

Here is the query I am using:

```
         SELECT A.type,
                A.name_en AS name_A,
                B.name_en AS name_B,
                C.name_en AS name_C

                FROM address AS A
                LEFT JOIN address AS B ON A.belongs_to = B.id
                LEFT JOIN address AS C ON B.belongs_to = C.id 
                WHERE A.name_en LIKE '%".$_GET['name']."%'
                "
```

It works fine when I type "sy" it gets me :

```
[type] = city
[name_A] =sydney
[name_B] =NSW
[name_C] =australia
```

However when I type "ken" it gets me:

```
[type] =suburb
[name_A] = kensington
[name_B] =sydney
[name_C] = NSW
```

It misses Australia. I want to make it flexible so It get me all the data up to the country name where the `type_order` is `1` or `belongs_to` is `0`. I have been trying to search for looping technique and could not find a good reference. Tell me If you have another suggestion to get this done or if you think my solution is the right one please help me with the looping thing or refer me to a good detailed reference regarding MySQL looping.

Comment: Does this have to be done in SQL?  I'd think this would be better done in the application logic which can say "Loop through until `belongs_to` is 0".

Comment: I don not see how that is possible!

Comment: you apparantly use [mysql_*](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php) function in your PHP please consider using [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: The table eventually will contain thousands of records. You are suggesting I retrieve them all and then I use PHP functions to get what I want?

Comment: `ORDER BY type_order ASC`?

Comment: This isn't going to be possible in pure SQL (at least not as described).  What's to stop it from "looping" forever if there are circular references?  It could be possible to write a MySQL stored function/procedure to do it but at that point you might as well use PHP.  If there is a fixed limit on how many parents anything can have then it should be possible though.

Comment: When `belongs_to` equals `0` or `order_type` equals `1`

Comment: using PHP means retrieving all the records which they could be thousands.

Comment: Why would it require you to do that?  Thousands isn't very many anyway.  Is there a limit on how many parents something can have?

Comment: wouldn't this consumes more processing resources thus takes longer. How about implementing say like 10 `LEFT JOIN` so it covers up to 10 names. In normal circumstances, it won't be beyond 5 (country,state,city....etc).

Comment: Adjacency list is one way to store hierarchical data, but there are [others too](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The technique you choose to keep linked data is so called "Adjacency List". There are no way to "loop" random depth A.L., in general. To see items from 'kensington' up to 'australia', you need one more join in query. You have to add one join to every additional row.

Look for alternative techniques such as "Nested Lists" and "Materialized Paths". 
OR use loop in PHP to iterate through Adjacency List items.

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing wrong in user joins. Your condition basically depends on your `WHERE` condition. Please provide the structure of the table, or you can try this:

```
SELECT A.type,
                A.name_en AS name_A,
                B.name_en AS name_B,
                C.name_en AS name_C

                FROM address AS A
                LEFT JOIN address AS B ON A.belongs_to = B.id
                LEFT JOIN address AS C ON B.belongs_to = C.id 
                WHERE A.name_en LIKE '%".$_GET['name']."%' or A.id=1
```

Comment: The thing is that this is only covering up to three `name_en` and is not flexible with places branching. sometimes I need `LEFT JOIN` four times or more to get to the country name.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT A.name_en AS name_A, NULL AS TYPE    

FROM tablename1 AS A
LEFT JOIN tablename1 AS B ON A.belongs_to = B.id                
WHERE A.name_en LIKE '%ken%' OR A.belongs_to = B.id OR A.belongs_to = 0

UNION ALL

SELECT NULL AS name_A, C.type
FROM tablename1 AS C
WHERE c.name_en LIKE '%ken%'
```

Hope this will help you